# Mac OS X: Where should I store save games for a game delivered as a bundle?

Tags: c++, macos

I'm porting a windows game to Mac OS X. I was wondering where I should store game data such as saved games, user profiles, etc and how I can retrieve that path programmatically in C++?

The game will be delivered as a "modern bundle" as specified [here](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFOundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Concepts/BundleAnatomy.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Save it under 
    ~/Library/Application Support/Your Game Name/

where "~" stands for the home directory of the user playing your game.

You may want to give this a read: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php

Comment: No it is not working for me. There is no Library under user/my_name, only one under user/shared.

Comment: Library is hidden by default (At least on Lion anyway), you can make it visible through the terminal: http://www.wikihow.com/See-Hidden-Folders-on-Mac-OS-X-and-Other-Recent-Models
... or you can view hidden files in a file-open dialog by hitting CMD+Shift+Period

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore when the Application needs to be sandboxed.

Answer (score 4):

```
~/Library/Application Support/GameName
```

You can access Cocoa objects using Objective-C++, this can be done by changing the suffix of to source code to `.mm` This enables you to combine both Objective-C and C++.

There are [several file system classes](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000055i) you can use.

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but let me file a complaint about the previous answers: ~/Library/Application Support is not one of the places non-technical users will look for data files. You might want to at least consider putting them in a new folder in the Documents directory; i.e., ~/Documents/MyGame.